# com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException when using MongoClient with list ServerAddress

Tags: java, mongodb, timeout, mongodb-java

I'm trying to deploy a replica database onto one server with different port and connect with it.
Everything is ok if I just use single ServerAddress and connect directly to Primary DB
like this:

```
mongoClient =new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("104.236.106.53", 27000));
morphia = new Morphia();
ds = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, "morphiaDB");
```

Everything work fine. But when I'm trying to use `List<ServerAddress>` like this:

```
List<ServerAddress> lstServer = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
lstServer.add(new ServerAddress("104.236.106.53", 27000));
lstServer.add(new ServerAddress("104.236.106.53", 27002));
lstServer.add(new ServerAddress("104.236.106.53", 27001));
mongoClient = new MongoClient(lstServer);
morphia = new Morphia();
ds = morphia.createDatastore(mongoClient, "morphiaDB");
```

It will end up with this error:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 10000 ms while waiting for a server that matches {serverSelectors=[ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}, LatencyMinimizingServerSelector{acceptableLatencyDifference=15 ms}]}. Client view of cluster state is {type=ReplicaSet, servers=[{address=G-Server-1:27000, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: G-Server-1}}, {address=G-Server-1:27001, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: G-Server-1}}, {address=G-Server-1:27002, type=Unknown, state=Connecting, exception={com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Exception opening the socket}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: G-Server-1}}]
at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getServer(BaseCluster.java:82)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getServer(DBTCPConnector.java:654)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.access$300(DBTCPConnector.java:39)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.getConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:503)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector$MyPort.get(DBTCPConnector.java:451)
at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getPrimaryPort(DBTCPConnector.java:409)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:182)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.insert(DBCollectionImpl.java:165)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:161)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:107)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:965)
at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:949)
at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:1013)
at org.mongodb.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:1000)
at com.learn.DAO.AuthorBookDAO.main(AuthorBookDAO.java:18)
```

Can anybody tell me what this error is or provide me some hint how to solve it?

Comment: My project is maven project working with morphia
and mongo-java-driver 2.12.2

Answer (score 0):

After searching on google. I'm find out that java can't recognize which is the primary database

```
GWReplication:PRIMARY> cfg=rs.conf();
{
    "_id" : "GWReplication",
    "version" : 1,
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "host" : "G-Server-1:27000"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "host" : "G-Server-1:27001"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "host" : "G-Server-1:27002"
            }
    ]
}
```

This is default config of my mongodb. And java can't understand G-Server-1 
So I fix it by change it to my above ip

```
GWReplication:PRIMARY> rs.config();
{
    "_id" : "GWReplication",
    "version" : 2,
    "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 0,
                    "host" : "104.236.106.53:27000"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "host" : "104.236.106.53:27001"
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "host" : "104.236.106.53:27002"
            }
    ]
}
```

Now it work fine. I know that it's a quite idiot way to fix but honestly I don't know how to make java to recognize my domain name or how to config it on ubuntu server(I deploy mongodb on host of digitalocean and this is first time I use ubuntu and self config a server) -_-

Answer (score 0):

Changing your replica set to ip address is actually the wrong way to go about it.

**Try this:**

1. Revert back to using the domain names in your replica set configuration.
2. Update your mongo client configuration with the replica set domain names.

   ```
    List<ServerAddress> lstServer = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
    lstServer.add(new ServerAddress("G-Server-1", 27000));
    lstServer.add(new ServerAddress("G-Server-1", 27002));
    lstServer.add(new ServerAddress("G-Server-1", 27001));
    mongoClient = new MongoClient(lstServer);
   ```

That should fix it. Spring Mongo actually uses the host name and port number to determine the primary replica as configured in the replica set.